# How to specify a database in a query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a PHP script to log in to  a website. Right now, I am making a "My Profile" page, where all you info, like `Username` and `Email` are displayed. I have MySQL set up. In MySQL, a database named `registeredusers` holds all the info like `username`, `password`, and `email`. I can use PHPMyAdmin to view it, but I must first select the database `registeredusers` to run a query on it. This is the command I am trying to run.

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

My table inside `registeredusers` database is called `users`. The username value is `username`. Id is just an incrementing number I use to identify each different account.

I want to be able to run this in the global query box. What would I have to change in the code to select `registeredusers` as the database I want to run it on?

Comment: how about specifiy it in your connect, or issue a "use registeredusers" command

Comment: Post how you're connecting to MySQL from PHP

Comment: I am using a PDO to connect. I am trying to use $pdo->exec("")

Comment: I reworded the title to better reflect the question. I updated thee tags and improved formatting for better readability. Please check and make sure that the question is what you intended. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If using mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "registeredusers");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Here is some more information on that http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

If you are using PDO (PHP5), you can use the following code which was taken from here (http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php):

```
$host = "yourHost";
$user = "yourUser";
$pass = "yourPass";
$db = "yourDB";

$cursor = "cr_123456";

try
{
  $dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pass");
  echo "Connected<p>";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() ."<p>";
}
```